# Search Box model where

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have problem with model with use where.

I have in artists controller

```
  def search
@artists = Artist.where(params[:search])
end
```

and view artist

```
<%= form_tag(search_path) do %>
<%= search_field_tag(:search,"Search") %>
<%= submit_tag("Search") %>
<% end %>
```

In the partial view are all artists

And when I search something I have error.

SQLite3::SQLException: no such column: test1: SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists"  WHERE (test1)

Comment: On which column of the `artists` table would you like to perform the search? `artists.name` maybe?

Comment: Yes. I can search for artists.name

Comment: so you might try: Artist.where(name: params[:search]) (you have to tell AR what you are intending to look for, i can't simple guess on which column to perform the query on)

Answer (score 1):

Should be:

```
   @artists = Artist.where("name = ?", params[:search])

   @artists = Artist.where(name: params[:search]) # It is better
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to search `Artist.name`, try changing your query to something like:

```
@artists = Artist.where("name = ?", params[:search])
```

That will produce a SQL query that looks like

```
SELECT "artists".* FROM "artists" WHERE ("name" = 'test1')
```

Instead of the one cited in your error message.

For more information on queries and how they work, you might want to look at:
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#conditions

Comment: [@artists = Artist.where("name = ?" params[:search])], it doesn't work, it should be "@artists = Artist.where("name = ?", params[:search])"。